# sqlalchemy to filter on list by table name and filters condition

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy ORM layer to communicate with RDS.
  Here this is common function for all tables to filter row.
  We pass table name, column to select, filters and date range.

`filter = { "company_guid": "xxxx", "status": "Active"}`

`filter` is dictionary which have key as column name and value is condition.
  Which work fine

but know I want filter on `status` column where value can be `Active` or `TempInActive`

So now filter become `filter = { "company_guid": "xxxx", "status": ["Active", "TempActive"}`
It not working because value is list, not string.
I know can use `result = session.query(Customers).filter(Customers.id.in_([1,3]))` but in my scenario table name and column names are function arguments.

```
def get_items_withvalue(self, table_name, column_name=None, attribute_value=None,
                        columns_to_select=None, date_value=False, filters=None):
    """
    @Summary: This method used to get data based on a condition.
    @param table_name (string): This is the table_name
    @param column_name (None/string): for the column_name
    @param attribute_value (None/list/string): for the column_value
    @params columns_to_select(None/list/string): columns to send in response
    @params filters(None/dict): where clause for rows to be fetched
    @return (list of dict): fetched rows or count from DB
    """
    data = []
    session = None
    try:
        # Get session which communicate with RDS
        session = self.get_session()
        table = str_to_class(table_name)
        if columns_to_select:
            data = []
        else:
            if isinstance(attribute_value, list):
                data = (session.query(table)
                        .filter(getattr(table, column_name)
                                .in_(attribute_value))
                        .all())
            elif date_value:
                data = (session.query(table)
                        .filter(cast(getattr(table, column_name), Date)
                                == attribute_value)
                        .all())
            elif filters:
                ## How to update following code to filter on list(in)
                # filters is dictionary
                data = (session.query(table).filter_by(**filters).all())
                ##
            else:
                data = (
                    session.query(table).filter(getattr(table, column_name)
                                                == attribute_value).all()
                )
    except Exception as err:
        self.logger.exception("Error fetching items ")
        raise Exception(err)
    finally:
        if session:
            session.close()
    if columns_to_select:
        return [row._asdict() for row in data]
    return [object_as_dict(row) for row in data]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

One way is to construct query string and do eval, but which is not good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the ORM I'll assume that what you call `table` in the function is actually a mapped ORM class.

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to handle both cases where the values of `filters` may be either a scalar value, in which case you'd like to filter on equality, or a list of values, in which case you'd like to test for presence in the list using `in_()`. However, a complicating factor is that you cannot use the `str` keys of `filters` directly in `filter()`. Hopefully I've understood.

I think you can solve this neatly by using `getattr` to get the column attribs from the table object, a conditional list comprehension and then unpacking the list into `.filter()`, for example:

```
filters = {'a': 'scalar', 'and': ['collection', 'of', 'values']}
(
    session.query(table).filter(
        *[
            getattr(table, k).in_(v)
            if isinstance(v, list)
            else getattr(table, k) == v
            for k, v in filters.items()
        ]
    )
)
```

This will produce the equivalent of `orm_table_object.column_attrib == val` if `val` is not a `list`, and `orm_table_object.column_attrib.in_(val)` if `val` is a `list`.

Comment: Let me try,  thanx

Answer (score 1):

Extending the above answer just with a `list` of conditions

```
filters = [orm_table_object.field_name_1 == expected_value_1]
if expected_value_2 is not None:
   filters.append(orm_table_object.field_name_2 == expected_value_2)
if expected_value_3 is not None:
   filters.append(orm_table_object.field_name_3 == expected_value_3)


session.query(table).filter(
    *[f for f in filters]
)
```